# What formatter pattern should I use to get '00123', '00001' strings from numbers '123' and '1' correspondingly?

Tags: java, string, string-formatting, formatter

I need to format numbers in a way that they should be preceded with zeros to contain 5 digits.

I don't get how to create patterns for java formatter.

I tried `%4d` but it doesn't adds zeros.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`%05d` should do it I believe

Comment: Cool :-)  The best list of formatting examples I can find is here: http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0120__Development/0200__printf-Method.htm

Answer (score 5):

```
int a=123;   
System.out.println(String.format("%05d",a));
```